# practical use for undef

Tags: ruby, undef

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [undef - Why would you want to undefine a method in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543774/undef-why-would-you-want-to-undefine-a-method-in-ruby)

Can anyone lay out a practical use for undef in ruby? I'm coming from languages like javascript and python that don't have it built in. You could of course simulate it in a language like javascript:

```
var obj = { func:function(){alert("works")} }
obj.func() // -> "works"
delete(obj["func"])
obj.func() //->obj.func() is not a function
```

but I've never really had use for that. Are there some common situations where undef is actually useful?

**EDIT** --
Just came across this in the book "The Ruby Programming Language":

> Another technique to prevent copying
>   of objects is to use undef to simply
>   remove the clone and dup methods. Yet
>   another approach is to redefine the
>   clone and dup methods so that they
>   raise an exception with an error
>   message that specifically says that
>   copies are not permitted. Such an
>   error message might be helpful to
>   programmers who are using your class.

Comment: see my response to the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can only say that I've never had a use for it in 5 years. Perhaps more usefully, grepping through the entire source of rails shows only 7 instances and they're all meta-programming related. (undef_method has rather more instances at 22). It appears to be useful for testing the behaviour of classes with and without modules mixed-in.

Hopefully someone can point out some more conventional uses for it.

**EDIT**
See this previous question: [undef - Why would you want to undefine a method in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543774/undef-why-would-you-want-to-undefine-a-method-in-ruby)

Comment: Hmm, interesting. So we have 1: to remove a method from a class to run a test with the method missing. 2: to remove all the methods from a class to create a completely blank proxy class. and 3: For some horrible condition based functionality. I'm going to wait a little longer to accept the answer to see if anyone responds with anything else but I'm sure this'll be it. I'd give you an upvote but apparently i can't yet.

Answer (score 6):

Blocking a child class from calling a method defined in the superclass (this is actually used in mongrel's `setup.rb`) (paraphrasing):

```
class Item
  def set
    do_something
  end
end

class ExecItem < Item
  undef set
end
```

Though I guess `undef_method` would have the same effect.