# How do I create a class without 'new' method?

Tags: ruby

I want a class that does not support instantiation via `new`, like the `Integer` class. I tried to inherit from `BasicObject`, but it still lets me create an instance with `new`.

Comment: How are you going to create the instances then, if not with `new`?

Comment: What if I want to make all methods class-methods? This question is theoretical and I want to know how standard classes without new are implemented

Comment: If you don't need instances of the class, then it's not a class, it's a module. Integer (and maybe a few other primitive types) is a special class in this regard: it's not a "real" class, with state and all. That said, this can be achieved with [`undef`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543774/undef-why-would-you-want-to-undefine-a-method-in-ruby).

Comment: I would argue if you want to disable the option to instantiate an instance then use a `module` instead of a `class`

Comment: Module is a better word to use in your case. You only create a class when you know you're going to use its instances at some point.

Comment: Ruby is a class-based object-oriented programming language. If you want to do prototype-based object-oriented programming, use another language, such as JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have several options, which I will present here (roughly) in the order of how "aggressive" they are in my personal opinion:

## Override the default `Object#initialize` with your own

You can override the default implementation of `Object#initialize` with your own implementation which does something different. In your case, say, [`raise`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-raise) an [`Exception`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Exception.html):

```
class Foo
  def initialize(*) raise TypeError, "`#{self.class}` cannot be instantiated." end
end

Foo.new
# TypeError: `Foo` cannot be instantiated.
# from (…):5:in `initialize'
```

The default implementation of [`Class#new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html#method-i-new) will automatically call your implementation of `Foo#initialize`, which will then `raise` an `Exception` and abort the object construction, or more precisely: it will abort the object *initialization*, since the object will have been constructed by the time `initialize` is called (otherwise, how would you call `initialize` if there is no object to call it on?) However, object construction is cheap, and the object will immediately be eligible for garbage collection, so it shouldn't matter.

For completeness' sake, here is (approximately) what the default implementation of `Class#new` looks like:

```
class Class
  def new(*args, &b)
    obj = allocate
    obj.send(:initialize, *args, &b) # `initialize` is `private`, must use `send`
    obj
  end
end
```

As you can see, by the time `initialize` is called, [`Class#allocate`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html#method-i-allocate) will have already constructed the object.

## Override the default `Class#new` with your own

You can override the default implementation of `Class#new` with your own implementation which does something different. In your case, say, `raise` an `Exception`:

```
def Foo.new(*) raise TypeError, "`#{self}` cannot be instantiated." end

Foo.new
# TypeError: `Foo` cannot be instantiated.
# from (…):3:in `new'
```

## Make `Foo::new` a `private` method

You can make the `new` method of the singleton class of `Foo` a [`private` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-private_class_method), that way, it can't be called with an explicit receiver:

```
Foo.private_class_method :new

Foo.new
# NoMethodError: private method `new' called for Foo:Class
# from (…):3:in `…'
```

This would, for example, still allow you to have special *factory methods* that construct instances of your class, e.g. something like:

```
def Foo.create_from_xml(file)
  # do stuff to parse `file`
  new(argument_parsed_from_file)
end
```

Note this sentence in the documentation of `Module#private_class_method`:

> Often used to hide the default constructor `new`.

and the code example directly following it.

## Undefine the `new` method from the singleton class of `Foo`

You could undefine the `new` method using [`Module#undef_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-undef_method). `undef_method` will prevent instances of the module from responding to that message completely, unlike [`Module#remove_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-remove_method), which will simply remove the method from the module, so that method lookup continues normally up the inheritance chain.

```
Foo.singleton_class.undef_method :new

Foo.new
# NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for Foo:Class
# from (…):3:in `…'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
module MyClassWithOnlyClassMethods

  extend self

  def foo
  end

end
```

Actually, you can do it without `extend self`, but you would have then to write `def self.foo` etc. for each method, which gets cumbersome.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. It should probably be a comment to the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18363040)

Comment: @JörgWMittag Why not? It sounds like the OP wants a class but no instances. Is it then not a reasonable idea to use a module instead of a class?

Comment: @kvorobiev Same question to you.

Comment: I think, it does provide an answer (my module **is** a class and you can not apply `new` to it; actually, it is the way we implement such classes in our project). @JörgWMittag : Aside from this, it's difficult to put this in a comment, because comments can't be multi-line. Of course I could describe the `extend self` trick without given an example, but it's better to understand if we see a concrete example.

Comment: The OP wrote in the question that they want "a class". Your answer does not show a class, it shows a module. The question also says "like `Integer`", and `Integer` *does* have instances, yet, it doesn't have a `new` method. Your answer doesn't address that. In a comment, the OP wrote that the question is "theoretical", IOW it is not about how best to write some code, it is about how to hide the `new` method. Your answer doesn't address that. And lastly, your answer isn't even an answer at all, it is a request for clarification "How about this?" and as such belongs in a comment or in chat.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: The OP wants a class without `new` method, not a class without instances. In the question, `Integer` is given as an example, which *does* have instances.

Comment: @JörgWMittag He also said *"make all methods class-methods"*. What good are instances if they have no methods? And `Integer` is only given as an example of a class *not supporting instantiation via `new`.* It has *lots* of instance methods and as far as I understand not even *any* class methods. I wouldn't get hung up on him saying the word "class" and I wouldn't read more his `Integer` example than what he actually said about it. Also, even if *he* actually does want a class, maybe someone else wondering about this doesn't, and I don't think answers are only for the question author.

Comment: @JörgWMittag : I understood the question in that the OP doesn't care whether he has one instance, or just a class. That's why I would consider your proposed solution as correct, but mine as correct as well. Maybe a more philosophical question: Can such a "module", which I proposed, be considered as a "class which is its own (sole) instance"? Actually, if we create a `Module`, we do **not** get a `Class` in the Ruby sense (because `Module <= Class` evaluates to `false`), although of course from the viewpoint of OO-design, it can be regarded as (singleton-) class.

Comment: @StefanPochmann : While I agree with your argument, the reasoning giving by Jörg also sounds reasonable. In hindsight, I think the question is not specified precisely, so we **should** have asked the OP for clarification, before posting an answer.